# How to disable button in jquery after onclick function, to avoid double form submission

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery. I am just trying to do simple thing in Jquery. I have a page from where I want to avoid multiple submission.

```
function removeAddApply{
  $("#addAndApply").attr("disabled","disabled");
}

<input id="addAndApply" type="button" class="button" value="Add & Apply" onclick="removeAddApply()"/>
```

I want to disable button when I trigger onClick function from the page.
Above is the code I am doing. Not sure what is wrong but its not working.

Complete function is

```
function removeConflictsOverrideReasons() {

      $("#removeConflictsReason").prop("disabled", true);
    if ($('.conflictsTable input:checkbox').is(":checked")) {
        var url = "/conflicts/conflictsRest/removeConflictsOverrideReasons";
        var selectedIssueSummaryIds = [];
         $('#conflictsDiv').find('.conflictsSelect:checked').each(function() {
             if($(this).val()) selectedIssueSummaryIds.push($(this).val());
         });

        $.post( url, { issueSummaryId: selectedIssueSummaryIds, userId: userId},
                function(data) {
                oReasonTable.fnReloadAjax();
                oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                clearConflictsChecked();
            });

    } else {
        alert('Please select Issue summary to remove');
    }
    $("#removeConflictsReason").removeAttr("disabled");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr` unless you are using really old version of jquery to set the property values.

```
jQuery("#addAndApply").prop("disabled", true);
```

[Read about the difference here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1)

You can also consider binding and unbinding events, `unbind` \ `bind` or `on` \ `off` (>=1.7), and if you need it only once you can bind it using `one` and get rid of the inline `onclick` attribute from the element.

```
  jQuery(function(){
         jQuery('#addAndApply').on('click', function(){
            //do something  
            disableAndRemoveHandlers.call(this);   
         });
  });

  function disableAndRemoveHandlers(){
    jQuery(this).prop("disabled",true).off('click'); //Make it disable and turn off event
  }
```

You also have a syntax error in function declaration. It should be

```
function removeAddApply(){
  $("#addAndApply").attr("disabled","disabled");
}
```

**Update**

Your issue is that you are making the button too early before the ajax call is completed (ajax is async), you need to do it in the ajax call success/failure or done callbacks.

```
function removeConflictsOverrideReasons() {
     var $elem = $("#removeConflictsReason");
     $elem.prop("disabled", true);
    if ($('.conflictsTable input:checkbox').is(":checked")) {
        var url = "/conflicts/conflictsRest/removeConflictsOverrideReasons";
        var selectedIssueSummaryIds = [];
        $('#conflictsDiv').find('.conflictsSelect:checked').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val()) selectedIssueSummaryIds.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.post(url, {
            issueSummaryId: selectedIssueSummaryIds,
            userId: userId
        },

        function (data) {
            oReasonTable.fnReloadAjax();
            oTable.fnReloadAjax();
            clearConflictsChecked();
            $elem.prop("disabled", false); //<---------Do it here
        });

    } else {
        alert('Please select Issue summary to remove');
    }
}
```

Comment: if prop doesn't work, he can use this code:if (typeof $.fn.prop !== 'function')
    $.fn.prop = function(name, value){
        if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            return this.attr(name);
        } else {
            return this.attr(name, value);
        }
    };

Comment: @shadesco true..  If he is using really really old verison of jq.. :) But in those old version attr used to do the job of prop. They just separated them out later.

Comment: I tried using prop too. But didn't work. I am using Jquery 1.8 jQuery("#addAndApply").prop("disabled", true);

Comment: button is not disabled. I can post the data multiple times.

Comment: @Manu Can you replicate it in a fiddle. Do you have any errors in the console? Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/zRRMc/ . Check it and update it with what you are doing.

Comment: I see the demo, I am doing the same thing but in my code it's not working. Let me post you my complete function from the code. I thought it would be simple.

Comment: @Manu Your issue is that you are making it enable so soon before ajax call is completed, you need to do it only on the success or error callback of your ajax post.